# I can't understand why this is giving me module error in colab

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, google-colaboratory, python-import

I am doing a project for learning. I have a got a code,  but when I run that code in Google Colab, I got some error. It says module not found. I am attaching the code and error message. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle
import os
import pandas as pd
import random
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4a7a7595e972> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 from keras.layers import Dense
      5 from keras.optimizers import Adam
----> 6 from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
      7 from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten
      8 from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.np_utils'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.
```

I tried this in pycharm. But some packages cannot be installed and gives an error. Some packages are not finding when I search to install it in pycharm. Please help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Keras have moved the to_categorical function. You should import it from tensorflow.keras.utils rather than keras.utils.np_utils. Change your import statement as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```